# Arithmetic Operation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select

I want to execute a SQL query in mysql something like the below:

```
SELECT
(0-5) AS `sqlTest`, if(`sqlTest` < 0, 'false', 'true')
```

But I am getting an error **"Unknown column 'sqlTest' in 'field list'"**

### Note

> This is not an exact query. Here the operands 0 and 5 will be replaced
>   with 2 big Select queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL, you can use a temporary to solve it;

```
SELECT @tmp := (0-5) AS `sqlTest`, if(@tmp < 0, 'false', 'true')
```

Simple demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/136).

Comment: Can you please mark the answer from @Joachim as the one you are looking for. It is a way to acknowledge the time spent by the community in answering your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hey i got the answer of your question. here,

try this,

`SELECT @var:=(0-5) AS sqlTest, if(@var< 0, 'false', 'true');`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @var:=(0-5) AS sqlTest, if(@var< 0, 'false', 'true');
```

Answer (score 1):

I arranged the subquery with a fictious identifier:

```
select if(x.`sqlTest` < 0, 'false', 'true') from (SELECT (0-5) AS `sqlTest`) x
```